# How to call a WinAPI function in QTP/UFT having a parameter that is a pointer to an application-defined callback function?

Tags: automated-testing, qtp

I was writing a function to get the handle of current active window in the Application. For that I am using Extern.Declare to declare and use WinAPI functions. I need to use  EnumChildWindows which will enumerate through the child window by passing the top window handle using GetTopWindow WinAPI.

EnumChildWindows has a parameter that is a pointer to an application-defined callback function, which I understand, is a limitation of the Extern object. What could be the workaround for this?

**UPDATE**

My algorithm is something like this :

Dim hwnd    ‘(Handle of my main Application)

top_hwnd = GetTopWindow (hwnd)

parent_hwnd = GetWindow (top_hwnd, GW_CHILD) ‘I need to do this to get the application handle since QTP/UFT gets confused with the Application handle and Ribbon handle

GetWindowHandleByClass(parent_hwnd , ClassName_child)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494(v=vs.85).aspx, and http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/enumchildwindows.html

This is a c# example, but you wrap this in a dll and import into QTP.

Also, depending on the window you might be over-engineering a bit.

If you top window is the parent, and the window you need is GW_PopUp with a class #32770 then perhaps you can use GetWindow instead.

Comment: I am using GetWindow(top_hwnd, GW_CHILD) to get the parent_hwnd. Since the parent has ‘n’ number of children, I need to enumerate through all of them to know if the specified window (identified through its parent and classname) is active and it is in focus. 
Here I use EnumChildWindows, however, I am uncertain about how to pass the second parameter which is a pointer to an application-defined callback function. I have modified my Question description with more information